# TCP communication has a random delay

Tags: tcp, delay

I made a very simple client->server program and it works as it should but sometimes it connects to server immideatly but in other cases it takes more than 20 seconds or it wont connect at all. It happens even if i start the client and server on SAME PC.

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace TCPListener
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("95.102.185.157", 8001);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        string message = Console.ReadLine();

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        ASCIIEncoding ncoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Byte[] transfer = ncoder.GetBytes(message);
        stream.Write(transfer, 0, transfer.Length);



        client.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace TCPServer
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.12");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, 8001);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + ip.ToString());
        Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved socket" + s.RemoteEndPoint);

        Byte[] b = new Byte[100];
        s.Receive(b);
        foreach (Byte byt in b)
        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(byt));

        }

        ASCIIEncoding ncoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Byte[] message = ncoder.GetBytes("cud");
        s.Send(message);

        s.Close();
        listener.Stop();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i would make sure you are completely shutting down the socket and tcplistener.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you construct the server's TcpListener with `IPAddress.Any` instead of the specific IP?

Comment: I cant really tell the difference because it wont connect in 70% of cases buy i think that it doesnt work completely with IPAdress.Any, same about localhost